# SailsJS beforeCreate and beforeUpdate duplicated method alternatives

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have a model and I check for some validations before create and update. In many instances, it applies to both beforeCreate and beforeUpdate. Is there a better way to merge these two functions, something like before_save in rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can define beforeValidate or afterValidate which will run on both save and create.